# How to replace part of an array based on another part of the array?

Tags: python, regex, list

my question is how do I scan "my_list" for "comp" and change the associated time value from 200 to "t" only if 200 is less than t?

```
t = 3000
comp = 'C1'
my_list = [[200, 'C1'],[4000, 'C2']]
```

Output:

```
my_list = [[3000, 'C1'],[4000, 'C2']]
```

The opposite could be done with this scenario as the list shouldn't change as "t" is less than "5000":

```
t = 3000
comp = 'C1'
my_list = [[5000, 'C1'],[4000, 'C2']]
```

Comment: Hence, The mutables.

Comment: you may consider accepting an answer that helped you understand and solve your problem! https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `deepcopy`:

```
t = 3000
comp = 'C1'
my_list = [[200, 'C1'],[4000, 'C2']]

for e in my_list[:]:
    if comp in e:
        if e[0] < t:
            e[0] = t

print(my_list)
```

**Eventually, one-liner**:

```
print([[t,e[1]] if e[1] == comp and e[0]<t else e for e in my_list])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[[3000, 'C1'], [4000, 'C2']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
my_list = [[t,k[1]] if( k[1]==comp and k[0]<t ) else k for k in my_list]
```

Comment: It would fail for: `my_list = [[200, 'C3'],[4000, 'C2']]`